# Increate xfs partition size lvm

Tags: linux, xfs

I am trying to increase xfs disk lvm but I am missing something

```
"/" size is 70 GB and I want to enlarge it to 90GB .
I enlarged the underlying /dev/sda size to 140gb (it was 120gb) So I have enough space to add. 
Also - vgdisplay lvdisplay shows nothing.
Any idea ?

lsblk
NAME                           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                              8:0    0   140G  0 disk
├─sda1                           8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                           8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                           8:3    0 137.2G  0 part
  ├─rhel_dent--sasacprd01-root 253:0    0    70G  0 lvm  /
  ├─rhel_dent--sasacprd01-swap 253:1    0   7.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─rhel_dent--sasacprd01-home 253:2    0  40.5G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                    

[root@sasacprd01 tmp]# xfs_growfs -D 23470080 /
4096 blocks 18350080
data size 23470080 too large, maximum is 18350080
```

SO -that didnt work.. `enter code here`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

1. `lvextend -L +90G /dev/mapper/rhel_dent--sasacprd01-root`
2. `xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/rhel_dent--sasacprd01-root`